# Analytic value of, or nontrivial lower-bound for $\inf_{\|z\|_2 \le 1}\|Az-b\|_p$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $b$ be a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $A$ be an $n \times n$ positive-definite matrix. Let $p \in [1,\infty]$, and define

$$
\alpha := \inf_{\|z\|_2 \le 1}\|Az-b\|_p.
$$

**Question 1.** Is there an analytic expression (or even a nontrivial lower-bound) for $\alpha$ in terms of $p$, $b$, and $A$ ?

**Question 2.** Same question when $A=\mbox{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ is a diagonal matrix.

**Question 3.** Same question when $p=2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Résumé:** *I don't know if the following lower-bound can be improved.*

---

Since $\|v\|_p \ge \min(1,n^{1/p-1/2})\|v\|_2$, we know that
$\alpha_p(A,b) \ge \min(1,n^{1/p-1/2})\alpha_2(A,b)$. Now, by "dualizing", we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
\alpha_2(A,b) &= \inf_{\|z\|_2 \le 1}\|Az-b\|_2 = \inf_{\|z\|_2 \le 1}\sup_{\|v\|_2 \le 1}v^\top(b-Az)\\
&= \sup_{\|v\|_2 \le 1}v^\top b+\inf_{\|z\|_2 \le 1}-v^\top Az
= \sup_{\|v\|_2 \le 1} v^\top b - \|Av\|_2\\
&\ge \sup_{\|v\|_2 \le 1} v^\top b - \|A\|_{op}\|v\|_2 = (\|b\|-\|A\|_{op})_+.
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
Putting things together gives the following lower-bound
$$
\alpha_p(A,b) \ge \min(1,n^{1/p-1/2})(\|b\|-\|A\|_{op})_+.
$$